# C - Returning Float values from a function and printing them

Tags: c

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here but this will always print the average variable at the end as 0.

I have tried multiple ways, and this is the closest I have come to getting the average with no errors or warnings and the warnings i got was 68 totalgross defaults to int and 68 counter defaults to int.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

float finalCalc();

int main(){

int yORn = 1;

float totalGross;
float counter = 0;
float commissionEarned;
float grossPay;
float overTime;
char employeeCode;

do{

counter++;


printf("Please enter employee code:\n");
scanf(" %c", &employeeCode);

float hoursWorked;
printf("Please enter the hours they worked:\n");
scanf("%f", &hoursWorked);

float hourlyWageRate;
printf("Please enter there hourly rate in œ:\n");
scanf("%f", &hourlyWageRate);

if(employeeCode == 's' || employeeCode == 'S'){
        printf("Please enter any commission they have earned in œ:\n");
        scanf("%f", &commissionEarned);}

if(employeeCode == 's' || employeeCode == 'S'){
        grossPay = (hoursWorked * hourlyWageRate) + commissionEarned;
        printf("Department: Sales\nEmployee Code: %c\nGross pay: œ%6.2f\n", employeeCode, grossPay);
}

else if(employeeCode == 'f' || employeeCode == 'F'){
        overTime = (hoursWorked - 35) * 1.5;
        grossPay = (hoursWorked + overTime) * hourlyWageRate;
        printf("Department: Factory\nEmployee Code: %c\nGross pay: œ%6.2f\n", employeeCode, 
grossPay);
}

else{
        grossPay = (hoursWorked * hourlyWageRate);
        printf("Department: Admin\nEmployee Code: %c\nGross pay: œ%6.2f\n", employeeCode, grossPay);
}

totalGross = totalGross + grossPay;
printf("Would you like to enter another employee? 1 for yes 2 for no\n");
scanf("%d", &yORn);

}while(yORn == 1);
float average = finalCalc(totalGross, counter);
printf("The total gross pay was: œ%6.2f\nThe average gross pay was: œ%0.2f", totalGross, average);

return 0;}

float finalCalc(totalGross, counter){
float averageGross = totalGross / counter;
return averageGross;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make everyone's life easier I strongly suggest that you edit your question to apply proper indentation to your code. If the logical structure is not visible at once, that's an invitation to misunderstand your code and introduce related bugs.

Comment: You should probably invest in a beginners book or two, or maybe even take a few classes.

Comment: Thank you Gerhardh, I haven't used stackoverflow before so wasn't sure, how to structure it but will keep this in mind for anything in the future. and I am studying a degree in programming and networking but I have only just started learning C and was told to use this website for help.

Answer (score 0):

`float finalCalc(totalGross, counter)` declares the parameters as int. int/int in this case yields 0. Declare as: `float finalCalc(float totalGross, float counter)`

You also need a prototype at the beginning, otherwise the compiler will assume the parameters are int and will convert your floats to int before calling the function.

I suggest to turn warnings of your compiler on. Most compilers will issue warnings for these cases.

Comment: Re “You also need a prototype at the beginning, otherwise the compiler will assume the parameters are int and will convert your floats to int before calling the function”: Without a prototype visible at the call, the default argument promotions are used. These convert `float` to `double`. In the function definition, failing to declare the parameters is a constraint violation in the current C standard and should result in a diagnostic. If a compiler accepts the program, the C standard does not say the type defaults to `int`…

Comment: … If it does not default to `double`, the function definition is incompatible with the call, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much!, I got myself confused with function declaration and that has cleared it up! Also got it all working with no warnings or errors!

Answer (score 0):

There are four obvious issues with your code and the way you use the compiler:

1. When you compile a C program during development you should always enable warnings. Unfortunately warnings are typically not enabled by default. If you use gcc you simply add the option `-Wall` to the command.
2. When you enable warnings the compiler will issue someting like

   ```
   test.c: In function ‘finalCalc’:
   test.c:68:7: warning: type of ‘totalGross’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   float finalCalc(totalGross, counter)
       ^~~~~~~~~
   test.c:68:7: warning: type of ‘counter’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   ```

   With integer division you get zero instead of a number betweeen zero and one.
3. Shouldn't the variable *counter* be an integer instead of a floating point number?
4. You need to check the return value from *scanf* to make sure a value of the correct type was entered by the user.

Comment: Thank you, I have enabled the warnings now! I had no idea that IDE's did that! surely would make more sense the have them auto enabled lol

Comment: @Davidbrooks92 Good that you got it working. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer you find helpful.